# Directive need to be refreshed when input change

Tags: angular, typescript

I made the following directive :

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myDisabled]'
})

export class DisableDirective implements OnInit {
    private el: HTMLElement;

    @Input('myDisabled') isDisable: boolean;

    constructor(el: ElementRef) { this.el = el.nativeElement;}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.disable();
    }

    private disable() {
        this.isDisable ? this.el.style.opacity = '0.65' : this.el.style.opacity = '1';
    }
}
```

This directive set the opacity of a button depend on an input : isDesable. This setting need to be refreshed when the input change, however, I don't know how to do it.

I use this directive like this :

```
<button class="btn" [myDisabled]="!sharedDetails.isEnabled">A button !</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways

```
_isDisabled: boolean;
@Input('myDisabled') 
set isDisable(value: boolean)  {
  this._isDisabled = value;
  this.disable();
}
```

or

```
// called every time after inputs are updated
// check the `changes` parameter for details if you have more than one input
ngOnChanges(changes) {
  this.disable();    
}
```

Comment: Tried the second way, work perfectly, just need to import OnChanges. Thanks !

Comment: Also tried the first way, work as well but i needed to remove the ":void" of the setter

Comment: Great, thanks for the feedback (not using TS actively myself).